# Buttons-how do i move one button to the right of another button

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, alignment

I have a delete button and one edit button on the same line.Both are to the right because i used float right.Now,the edit button is to the left of the delete button and i want the edit button to be at the right of the delete button.

It may seem stupid but i have no clue.Have a great day and if you take the time to answer, thank you!
---HTML---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>To Do List</title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1 class="header">To Do List</h1>
        <div id="toDoForm">
            <input id="toDoInput" placeholder="What would you like to do?">
            <button id="dynamicButton" type="button">Add</button>
        </div>

        <ol id="toDoList">
        </ol>

        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="notify.min.js"></script>

        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "script.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

---CSS---

```
.deleteButton {
    font-style: normal;
    color: red;
    float: right;
    font-size: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;

    /*display: none !important;*/
}

.deleteButton:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 22px;
}

.editButton {
    background-color: yellow;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
}

#dynamicButton {
    height: 35px;
    float: left;
}

.buttonGroupAll {
    display: flex;

}

li{
    margin: 10px 0px;
    font-size: 25px;

    float: left;
    clear: both;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: green;
}

li:hover .deleteButton {
    /*display: inline-block !important;*/
}

#toDoInput {
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 16px;
    float: left;
}

.header {
    margin-left: 16px;
}
```

---JS---

```
//fire add Element Function when addButton is pressed
let addButton = document.getElementById("dynamicButton");
addButton.addEventListener('click',function(){
    addElement();
});
//add Element to OL 
function addElement() {
    let text = $("#toDoInput").val();
    if(!text){
        $.notify("Text is required!",{
            position:"top-left",
            className:"warn"
        });
        return;
    }
    //Create li
    let newItem = document.createElement("li");
    newItem.innerHTML = text;
    //Create del button
    let i = document.createElement("i");
    i.className = "fas fa-times-circle deleteButton";
    //append del button to li
    newItem.appendChild(i);
    //create edit button
    let editButton = document.createElement('i');
    editButton.className = "fas fa-edit editButton";
    //Append edit button to li
    newItem.appendChild(editButton);
    //append li to ol
    document.getElementById("toDoList").appendChild(newItem);
    //clear input value
    document.getElementById("toDoInput").value = "";
}

let deleteButton = document.getElementsByClassName("deleteButton");
let toDoList = document.getElementById("toDoList");

 document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    if(e.target && e.target.className.includes('deleteButton')){
          console.log(e.target);
          toDoList.removeChild(e.target.parentNode);
     }
 });

var input = document.getElementById("toDoInput");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    console.log(event);
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
   event.preventDefault();
   addElement();
  }
});
```

Comment: just change the order of your html objects

Comment: the problem is i create my edit button only in js so i dont know how to change the order.If you could type the code snippet it would be greatly apreciated

Comment: then change the order of your JS when you create the objects or create empty divs in HTML and select the correct ones when appending new DOMs. If you provide a snippet (codepen / jsfiddle / SO) I can go for it.

Comment: all my code is provided above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is to change the order of your element creation process because the browser will render the html from top to bottom.

Also use developer tools to debug / investigate your rendered frontend to find the bugs.

I highly recommend https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools

```
//fire add Element Function when addButton is pressed
let addButton = document.getElementById("dynamicButton");
addButton.addEventListener('click',function(){
    addElement();
});
//add Element to OL 
function addElement() {
    let text = $("#toDoInput").val();
    if(!text){
        $.notify("Text is required!",{
            position:"top-left",
            className:"warn"
        });
        return;
    }
    //Create li
    let newItem = document.createElement("li");
    newItem.innerHTML = text;



//create edit button
    let editButton = document.createElement('i');
    editButton.className = "fas fa-edit editButton";
    //Append edit button to li
    newItem.appendChild(editButton);



//Create del button
    let i = document.createElement("i");
    i.className = "fas fa-times-circle deleteButton";
    //append del button to li
    newItem.appendChild(i);
    //append li to ol
    document.getElementById("toDoList").appendChild(newItem);
    //clear input value
    document.getElementById("toDoInput").value = "";
}



let deleteButton = document.getElementsByClassName("deleteButton");
let toDoList = document.getElementById("toDoList");

 document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    if(e.target && e.target.className.includes('deleteButton')){
          console.log(e.target);
          toDoList.removeChild(e.target.parentNode);
     }
 });

var input = document.getElementById("toDoInput");
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    console.log(event);
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
   event.preventDefault();
   addElement();
  }
});
```